# Updating div with input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me please...i thought id been learning but think i was wrong.

Im trying to print out the value from a ul li option using .change()

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.front-color').change(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('.color_option_hide').hide(); 
        $('#color_option').text(color);
        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

Works great! Other than the fact that #color_option isnt actually showing the value!

Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: The code looks like it might be fine, but without html we can't help you.  What does your `console.log(color);` display?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5r19pf96/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vJx5Te0Q this is the HTML code im using

Comment: Forgot to mention! The input comes from a ul li NOT a select option....sorry!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7yfrcTyM this is the form part (its not complete i know, but the list is pretty long but you get the idea....)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not posting HTML to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the exact problem. As you experience, somethimes there is some problems that I don't know what is the exact problem. So I give you some codes for test. I hope that it will be helpful.

**1) changing $('#color_option').text(color); like follow**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.front-color').change(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('.color_option_hide').hide();

        $('#color_option').html(color);

        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

**2) changing $('#color_option').text(color); like follow**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.front-color').change(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('.color_option_hide').hide();

        document.getElementById("color_option").innerHTML(color);

        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

**3) Actually, if above codes, including your code, do not work, I think the selector will be a real problem. Recheck selector and tag's id. And check if the selector work well like follow.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.front-color').change(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('.color_option_hide').hide();

        console.log(document.getElementById("color_option"));
        // or
        console.log($('#color_option').length); // if length === 0, the seletor has problem

        console.log(color);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou Wallah, it was actually the selector, i changed it to a class and it worked out great! :)